# How to use javascript modules objects (HTML + JS embeed) with React

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

I would like to use javascript modules defined as, for instance:

```
new Accordion({
    items: [{
        title: 'First section',
        content: 'Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscipit eget, quam. Integer ' +
                 'ut n eque. Vivamus nisi metus, molestie vel, gravida in, condimentum sit ' +
                 'amet, nunc. Nam a n ibh. Donec suscipit eros. Nam mi. Proin viverra leo ut ' +
                 'odio. Curabitur malesuada. V estibulum a velit eu ante scelerisque vulputate.'
    }, {
        title: 'Second section',
        content: 'Sed non urna. Donec et ante. Phasellus eu ligula. Vestibulum sit amet purus. ' +
                 'V ivamus hendrerit, dolor at aliquet laoreet, mauris turpis porttitor velit, ' +
                 'faucibus i nterdum tellus libero ac justo. Vivamus non quam. In suscipit ' +
                 'faucibus urna.'
    }, {
        title: 'Third section',
        content: 'Cras dictum. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et ' +
                 'm alesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in ' +
                 'faucibus orci l uctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Aenean lacinia ' +
                 'mauris vel est.'
    }, {
        title: 'Fourth section',
        content: 'Dies iræ, dies illa, dies tribulationis et angustiæ, dies calamitatis et '+
                 'm iseriæ, dies tenebrarum et caliginis, dies nebulæ et turbinis, dies tubæ '+
                 'et clangoris s uper civitates munitas et super angulos excelsos.'
    }]
}).inject(document);
```

in order to produce a [collapsable bootstrap accordion](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-example-accordion), but with React.

I can't seem to find a way to manage this as it mutates the DOM in the injection phase, which React hates.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: What would the desired output look like?

Comment: I updated the post, you were right it was not clear thanks :)

Comment: You need to create an `Accordion` component, that takes the items in its props and uses them to render some HTML. At the moment, there's a risk that this question is too broad...

Comment: An accordion is some HTML + javascript in order to manage the clicks events. 

Yes, I could write my own accordion, but I would have to do this for each javascript bootstrap components and this is just reinventing the wheel.

At my company, they decided to wrap the HTML + JS that produce an accordion into an object, the one used above. You can see it as a kind of component.

But I don't know how to use that kind of object that wraps HTML + JS logic with react, because this object has to be inserted in the DOM with the inject function which breaks virtual DOM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I've talked to the guys responsible for this wrapping of bootstrap into objects components and they confirmed me it was unusable with any VDOM libraries.